# 15 Puzzle Image Checking With Handler

Tags: vb.net, properties, handler, default, picturebox

I will make this clear right now this IS homework. I do not expect full answers but they are welcome.

I was assigned to make a 15 puzzle in Visual Basic. Here is an example of what the game looks like (this is what I have so far):

[image: A normal 15 puzzle game.]

What I need help with is checking and moving the images. When I click on PictureBox 1 that you see at the bottom right, it should check the image below it, beside and above it to see if the image at that location is My.Resources.NONE. (NONE is a png image I imported). If an adjacent cell is NONE, then the two images are to swap with each other. Each PictureBox has a Handler at the address and all the images are in a two-dimensional PictureBox array (4x4).

I have set up a sub for it like so, but am not sure what to put inside it. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub mypic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

UPDATE:

I have did some more research and figured out a few things. This is my current approach:

```
 Private Sub mypic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim x, y, w, z As Integer
    ClickedPicture = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    x = ClickedPicture.Left
    y = ClickedPicture.Top
    If ClickedPicture(x + 1, y).Image = Nothing Then
        ClickedPicture(x + 1, y).Image = ClickedPicture(x, y).Image
        ClickedPicture(x, y).Image = My.Resources.NONE
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I have now is that it is saying ClickedPicture cannot be indexed because it has no default property. What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend separating your display from your logic.  Don't move the picture boxes, just change which image they display.  Create a 4X4 array with integers 0 - 15.  The integers can indicate which picture to show from an array of images.  Let index 0 be the empty square.  Then when you need to "move" one, just swap the values in the array.  In the OnPaint method of your form, loop through the 4x4 array and set the pictureBox Image properties to the correct images.

You can find out about VB's Default properties in section 9.7.3 of the language spec:

```
9.7.3 Default Properties
A property that specifies the modifier Default is called a default property. Any type 
that allows properties may have a default property, including interfaces. The default 
property may be referenced without having to qualify the instance with the name of the 
property.
```

I presume that ClickedPicture is a PictureBox.  You are trying to call it using array notation:  ClickedPicture(x + 1, y) but since it is not an array, it then tries to see if there is a Default property that can take an index and there is none.

Comment: I planned on having them just swap display images. Something like

`pictureArray(r + 1, c).Image = pictureArray(r, c).Image`
`pictureArray(r, c).Image = My.Resources.NONE`

I guess this is a bad idea?

Comment: Since it is a homework assignment, it is probably ok.  But if you were writing the app to sell, for example, keeping the logic separate from the display makes it easier to port the game to different platforms, with minimal changes.

Comment: I completely agree with you. If this were my Java or C class I would take it more seriously, but VB is not my taste. The way I was trying to do it is not working. It is saying the ClickedPicture has no default property. I have gotten 100% on all my other assignments so I think I'll settle for a low C on this one. Not worth the trouble right now.

Thanks for your help.